# GroupBox visibility in a Template XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-controls

```xml
<GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=FilterGroupName}" 
         Height ="Auto" 
         IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelected}" 
         IsVisible="{Binding Selected}" />
```

I get an error message saying that the visibility is readonly, in this case how to toggle the visibility?

Comment: Can't understand why it is readonly, is it custom GroupBox control?
Anyway you can warp it by a `<Grid>` layout contaner and set visibility to a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind to the `Visibility` property to change the visibility of a control.

In your case the variable that you bind to is a bool, so you need a converter that changes the bool to a `Visibility` type variable